# How to use Nuxt together with Vue Cli 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently using Nuxt.js to scaffold my Vue app. Is it possible to use Nuxt as part of a Vue Cli 3 project so I can benefit from both? I can't find instructions from their official docs.

Comment: Run `vue ui`, from there you can integrate Nuxt directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/andoshin11/vue-cli-plugin-nuxt-starter-template#readme which is a vue cli 3 plugin for nuxt. As of this answer, please beware of the warning at the page which reads as:

`This plugin may cause some issues depending on the combination of your vue-cli setups. Feel free to send any scale of issues. All of your feedbacks are gold to me.`

Comment: Version of nuxt is very old